# NetworkManager - failed to retrieve SIM object

Tags: linux, debian, networkmanager

I have cellular usb dongle
HUAWEI E3372h
which connected to BananaPi based on Linux Debian 10 and NetworkManager package installed.

Dongle worked properly for 2 weeks and suddenly stop working.
Once I've looked into syslog I've found this:
NetworkManager - failed to retrieve SIM object: NO SIM object availabe

I'd like to know how to prevent it.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried putting the SIM card from the dongle into an old phone and see if it connects to the network? Maybe the SIM went bad or it's not making good contact in the dongle?

Comment: Tnx, I've tried. SIM is good and internet working properly even on Banana Pi it just to stable